# Division in Banach Lattice Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, banach-lattices

Let X be a Banach Lattice Algebra and $X_+=\{f\in X: f>0\}$. Let $f:X_+\rightarrow X$ be continuously differentiable.

Question: When does the expression $\frac{f'(x)}{x}$ for $x\in X_+$, make sense?  why is it allowed to divide by the positive element?
 I saw such expression in an article, I want a justification for defining it.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting reasonable axioms for a Banach lattice algebra, it follows that $X_+$ is open. As long as $X$ is commutative, this means $f^\prime(x) \cdot x^{-1}$ and it does make perfect sense since $f$ is differentiable.

Here positive most likely means strictly positive and such element should be invertible (again, it is not clear what is a Banach lattice algebra).

Comment: But if X is not particularly mentioned to be commutative, does it make sense?

Comment: @ShinningStar does $\frac{x}{y}$ make sense for invertible matrices?

Comment: yes in that case $\frac{x}{y}=x.y^{-1}$

Comment: @ShinningStar why not $y^{-1}x$?

Comment: yes can be so. thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please refer me to these axioms to prove $X_+$ is open.

Comment: @ShinningStar me?

Comment: yes sir I want to prove that this positive cone is open.

Comment: @ShinningStar I think that your request is inappropriate; Banach lattice algebra is not a standard notion; it is your duty to give us the definition.

Comment: the (real) vector lattice X is called a (real ) lattice ordered algebra if
X is also an associative algebra with the property that $x,y\in X_+$ implies $xy\in X_+$. So if its a Banach lattice, we are having Banach lattice algebra also known as $l-algebra$.

Comment: Sir even if $X_+$ is not open, this $\frac{f'(x)}{x}$ makes sense?